# Determine the signature of a method using SourceMethod

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

In my Eclipse plugin I want to get the signature of a method from a SourceMethod object. SourceMethod has a method called getSignature that returns a String of the following form:

(I)V

Using this link
http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0286.html
I know how to parse this String. It is a method with an Integer as Parameter and void as return type. However, I'm asking myself if there isn't a better way to get the method signature?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the org.eclipse.jdt.core.Signature class, which provides methods for en-/decoding method signature strings.